# How to use \Pnodecount when there are more than one \curvepnodes invocations?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, pst-plot

Assume that there are 2 `\curvepnodes` macros invoked as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-3)(4,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=6]{0}{360}{.5 t PtoC}{I}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=6]{0}{360}{1 t 36 add PtoC}{O}
    \def\points{}%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (I\i)(O\i)}}
    \expandafter\pspolygon*[linecolor=red]\points
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

1. How to use `\Pnodecount` in this case?
2. If `plotpoints` in the first is different from the last, how to reference to one of the `\Pnodecount` by a root node name?
3. Bonus question: How to make `\expandafter\pspolygon*[linecolor=red]\points` functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `\Pnodecount`! The name is build by the forth parameter: `\Inodecount` and `\Onodecount`. However, I do not know what exactly you want to draw.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-3)(4,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=6]{0}{360}{.5 t PtoC}{I}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=6]{0}{360}{1 t 36 add PtoC}{O}
    \def\points{}%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Inodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (I\i)(O\i)}}
    \psset{linecolor=red}
    \expandafter\pspolygon\expandafter*\points
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

with `pst-poly`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}
foo \PstStarFive*[unit=2,linecolor=red] bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is not easy in fact of the optional argument. Use `\psset{linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=\pslinecolor}` instead of the star.

Comment: for a star simply use `\multido{\iI=0+1}{\Inodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (I\iI)(O\iI)}}`. However, use `pst-poly` instead

Comment: How about `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pspolygon\expandafter*\points`

Comment: `\expandafter\pspolygon\expandafter*\points` is enough, but makes no sense, you have to set the linecolor anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `\Pnodecount` since you already know how many nodes you're placing along the curve.  Also, I would do my own kind of work-around for the polygon.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{document}

\def\mymaxvalue{6}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)

    \def\circI{ 0.5 t PtoC }
%    \psparametricplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{360}{  \circI  }
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\mymaxvalue]{0}{360}{ \circI }{I}

    \def\circQ{   1  t 36 add PtoC }
%    \psparametricplot[linecolor=red]{0}{360}{ \circQ  }
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\mymaxvalue]{0}{360}{ \circQ }{Q}

    \pscustom[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid,linecolor=red]{
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Inodecount}{
%      \psdot(I\i)\uput[75](I\i){$I_\i$}
%      \psdot(Q\i)\uput[75](Q\i){$Q_\i$}
      \psline(I\i)(Q\i)
      \ifnum\i<\number\numexpr\mymaxvalue-1\relax\relax\psline(Q\i)(I\number\numexpr\i+1\relax)\fi
    }}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\Pnodecount` macro is not strictly speaking `\Pnodecount`.  You defined two collections of nodes.  So, there are two macros:  `\Inodecount` and `\Qnodecount` (I avoid using `O` because I can never tell when I've mistyped it as a zero, but in your example this would be `\Onodecount`).  This particular point is not all that clear from the documentation, you need to look into the `pst-node.tex` file to see how it's defined there.

Sorry, forgot that you wanted it filled.

Comment: Sorry. Using `\pscustom` is not my interest.